# passing variable into class (php)

Tags: php, oop, variables

Here is the code:

```
require('password.php');
class Authorization
{

var $users = array(
    'admin' => $password,    // User 1

); //........
```

how do I pass a variable declared in `password.php` into the Authorization class?

Comment: When you instantiate the class, pass the value in as an argument to the constructor and use it to set the property then

Comment: The PHP/4 OOP syntax was replaced by something better 10 years ago. It's time to get used to it. Additionally, your code should trigger an error message: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE)** If you cannot see it you need to configure your PHP environment to display error messages.

Comment: Google fodder: [*"Dependency Injection"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: @pellmellism - You do not understand OOP - You cannot pass a variable into a class. You CAN pass a variable into an object

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables in the class but you cannot pass to the class itself without a constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    $VarA = 0;

    function __construct($NewVarA = 0) {
        $this->VarA = $NewVarA;
    }
}
```

If you dont want to use constructors consider using a function instead of a class.

Comment: same named constructors are now obsolete. And also, this code snippet does not really help answer the OP's question.

Comment: @raidenace Was not even aware it had depreciated, fixed to reflect.

Comment: @DarkBee, Wobbles has answered it for me.

Comment: @DarkBee as of 5.3.3 same name functions are treated as normal functions and not constructor anymore.

Comment: Yup, just watched the docs, was actualy unaware of it as well. Thx for the information :)

Comment: `$this->VarA = $NewVarA;`

Comment: @MarkBaker this is what I get for not using PHP in so long lol

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think you mean this:

```
require('password.php');

class Authorization
{
    function __construct($myVariable) {
        // do something
    }
}

// Now you can do this, where $someVariable is defined in password.php:
$foo = new Authorization($someVariable);
```

Comment: Don't get fooled by the original code. Remember that you cannot write arbitrary code outside methods ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Oops; didn't even look at that part. Thanks. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell - the only thing to point out would be that $somevariable can be defined in password.php ...

Comment: I noticed that the question as well as all the answers were downvoted. I had downvoted @Wobbles answer, but I provided my explanation and when he corrected his answer, I removed the downvote for him. I hate when people downvote without commenting!

Comment: @raidenace No joke. Very annoying.

Comment: @EdCottrell - Somebody is trigger happy on the down vote